# Obtain siginfo_t when handling signals with kqueue

Tags: macos, freebsd, kqueue

Is there a way to obtain `siginfo_t` struct when handling signals with `kqueue`?
(On Linux when handling signal with `epoll` similar `struct signalfd_siginfo` is obtained by simply reading from `signalfd`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unfortunately not possible.

Signal delivery notifications via `kqueue` occurs after the process itself has already reacted to the signal; i.e. they are a post-delivery notification, rather than an in-delivery notification.

If the process receives multiple signals between calls to `kevent`, then all the system does is aggregate the number of times the signal has been delivered in the `data` field of the `kevent` structure.

This means that there's no way to obtain the signal information as, by the time you've called the `kevent` data, the signal has already been delivered to the process, and the signal details have been discarded. There is no internal mechanism that keeps a record of the underlying signal information which could be delivered by the `kevent`.

> I was reading some of the big nerd ranch book which seems to indicate that the kqueue handling for signals would not occur if there was a handler registered for the process. This does not appear to be the behaviour on Yosemite, you receive the event for signals even if there is a handler registered using either `sigaction` or `signal`.